# run webots without the visualization

Tags: webots

I am wondering if we can run webots without the visualization? I would like to run some simulations (which are best run offline - without graphics). I am open to creating a world/choosing-defining a robot using the webots UI. However once the world is saved,I would like to access all the details of the world+robot offline (without graphics - so that simulations run faster). Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

This possible by using the `--batch` and `--minimize` command line options, see details [here](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/starting-webots). You can also pass the world file as an argument to Webots. If not provided, Webots will load the previously opened file.